# Web Macro - Record and Playback

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, imacros

I am working on a project where our users logs in to our site and can go to any site from our site (in an iframe) and perform and bunch of actions on the child site. Our app will record the actions, and then play back to the user.

I have briefly looked into Selenium, WebDriver, Sikuli, Chickenfoot, iMacros, etc., but not sure if they will do this in a simple and elegant way.

My requirements

1) The record function should be available within any browser/ any OS.
2) No extension or plugin or any special install needed on client browsers to record.
3) Code generated from record is in an open format - XML/ JSON/ Java etc.
4) The code can be executed by back-end as part of play back.

Thank you,
Ramesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with iMacros only and it meets your demands.

iMacros can work in:

- FireFox
- Chrome
- Internet Explorer

iMacros workes on:

- Windows (32 or 64 bit)
- Linux (Centos or Ubuntu and you need a GUI - Graphic User Interface)
- MAC OSX (works fine on this OS too)

The code of iMacros is open format and supports use of other programming languages like PHP, Python, Java, JavaScript etc. Read about it here http://wiki.imacros.net/Automation
I prefer JavaScript.

You can see here the demonstration on how iMacros works. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36ZEgrKJxeU

iMacros has some limitations but they can be surpassed.